# Keeping i18n resources synced

Tags: java, properties, editor, internationalization

I am looking for an editor/comparator for i18n property files that would help me keep different language files in sync.

Basically, something that would compare a bunch a of property files and show which keys are not present in a particular language.

a property would look something like

```
component.titlepage.title = hello world
```

A simple diff is not possible since the right-hand-side will be different from a language to another.

Our current infrastructure:

- Java application
- Built using maven2
- Different i18n property files for different components of the system. (1 property file per language per component)

Comment: could you elaborate on your translation process?

Comment: Basically, we are developing the application in english. Then we have contributors that sometime provide translations in other languages on their own. However, they do not necessarily do it for every version. Moreover, they might miss a key or a even a whole file when they are translating it the first time.So we want something to quickly pinpoint which keys are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) tool, which I typically run as part of every continuous integration build which is done after every check-in to the main branch, will tell you if any given set of properties files has an inconsistent set of properties.  When I first started using Checkstyle, I indeed found that a few of my properties files were missing a small number of properties.

This won't help on the editor end, but it *will* help you efficiently identify any gaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, I find the ResourceBundle Editor plugin very handy. You can edit several properties files at the same time and you have warnings when a key is missing in one of the files.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a number of web applications that allow you to do that (along with many other activities). To name a few:

- [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com) (disclaimer: my company builds this product)
- [Transifex](http://www.transifex.net)
- [Get Localization](http://www.getlocalization.com)