# Is there a convenient way in VS.NET 2010 to copy new resource file entries from default resx files to specific language resx files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, localization

I can't imagine this hasn't been asked before somewhere because the demand seems obvious: when localizing an ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2010, I use Resharper to move strings to resx-files in App_LocalResources, copy the default language resx file, rename it to a specific language file, and enter the translations.

However, whenever there are additions to the default language file (because the aspx file changes), I need to *copy them manually* to the resx file of the specific language.

I guess there is an easy way to do this, a tool, an add-on. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never found anything that was great and did everything i wanted, however I've used this in the past and was ok.

[ZetaResourceEditor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html)

Ive also used a web based editor, we had a need for the translators to access the resource files.  I think one of my programmers had to fix a couple of bugs with it but might be a good start.

[LavaBlast](http://blog.lavablast.com/?tag=/resx)

Comment: Nice link. Thanks. If you remember the name of the web based editor, I'd appreciate that. We have pretty much the same situation.

Comment: No worries, I have updated my answer with details of the web based editor.

Comment: You can also have a look at this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7186019/16026